# Episerver form container render issue

Tags: episerver

I am trying to add the elements to episerver form container. I get this in the preview window

[image]

You can see the text is behind the add/drop control.

I am using plain form and no additional css is being used. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: You should probably add markup from your view(s) to help people understand what is being rendered.

Comment: which views? I haven't created any custom view. This is what comes with default episerver forms.