# Episerver version and form version causing issue with render

Tags: episerver

I am trying to create a form using nuget package in Episerver 10. The form version that is compatible with that version of episerver is 4.8. When I add form elements in the form container I get the below view

[image]

You can see the issue with the image. How do I fix it? I am not using any custom css or anything. It is out of the box form package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Episerver form container render issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171865/episerver-form-container-render-issue)

Comment: @TedNyberg I tried to explain here a bit better. Still haven't fixed the issue. Any pointers from you?

Comment: I would suggest editing the original question to clarify it to avoid duplicates. Regretfully I haven't experienced this problem, but I haven't tried the `Forms` add-on with the Alloy template project.